# Linker Error: Undefined Reference to Function

Tags: c++11, g++, linker-errors, undefined-reference

I'm running into a linker error when I try to compile my code.

When I compile using `g++ *.cpp -std=c++11 -o run` I get the following error:

```
main.cpp:(.text+0x355): undefined reference to `Actions(mBoard&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::set<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I've tried compiling and linking all the files separately to no avail. Its not a member function so it's not a label issue. I've also tried to use `g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp mAI.cpp -o run` to make sure it is in fact compiling and linking both files but no luck.

What's really making me crazy is that it's not complaining about the `Translate` function that's declared and defined in the same way as the Actions function.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

## mAI.hpp

```
#ifndef MAI_HPP
#define MAI_HPP

#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <tuple>
#include "mBoard.hpp"
using namespace std;

void Actions(mBoard const &state, string const playerColor, set<string> moveList);
tuple<int, int> Translate(string index);

#endif
```

## mAI.cpp

```
#include "mAI.hpp"

std::set<char> blackPieces = {'r', 'n', 'b', 'q', 'k', 'p'};
std::set<char> whitePieces = {'R', 'N', 'B', 'Q', 'K', 'P'};

void Actions(mBoard const &state, string const playerColor, set<string> moveList)
{
    //Do some stuff
}

tuple<int, int> Translate(string index)
{
    //Do different stuff
}
```

## main

```
#include "mAI.hpp"
#include "mBoard.hpp"
#include <set>
#include <tuple>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{

  mBoard dasBoard;
  set<string> moveList;
  string color = "White";

  cout<<"TEST - Translate: f6 to file, rank: ";
  tuple<int, int> test;
  test = Translate("f6");
  cout << get<0>(test) << ", " << get<1>(test) << endl;

  Actions(dasBoard, color, moveList);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I put that in and get the same linker error...

Comment: Done and done with no change. I can see main but out of curiosity why in mAI.cpp? With the include of the .hpp wouldn't it include there automatically?

Comment: [mcve] needed. And incidentally see [Why is “using namespace std” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/1362568)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That sounds like a very old gcc compiler. That was a problem during abi change in earlier versions of gcc and installed libraries on the system.

using `-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0` and recompile all maybe help.

See also this documentation:
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc%2B%2B/manual/using_dual_abi.html

BTW:
I can compile and link your code with gcc 7.3.1 ( fedora ) without any error. Some warnings of unused vars after cut and paste your code and only add an empty aBoard class. So I believe there is nothing wrong with your code.

From the documentation:

> If you get linker errors about undefined references to symbols that involve types in the std::__cxx11 namespace or the tag [abi:cxx11] then it probably indicates that you are trying to link together object files that were compiled with different values for the _GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI macro. This commonly happens when linking to a third-party library that was compiled with an older version of GCC. If the third-party library cannot be rebuilt with the new ABI then you will need to recompile your code with the old ABI.